# Sliding Images with Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I am very new to Xamarin. What I am trying to do is build a simple application that has 3 images on it. Each image needs to slide horizontally to show the next image. I got this idea from a children's game called "mix and match". The game lets you change the head, body and feet of a cartoon animals.

So if I have a set of 5 images that are split into thirds (head,body,feet), how can I display the images on the screen so I can get them to slide?

I tried to stack 3 gallery controls but I could not get the images to fill the screen.

The screen should look something like this;

[image]

Can this be built in Xamarin for Android or IOS?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS you could use `UIPageControl`. You would have a different `UIPageControl` object for Head, Body, Feet. The idea is that you will have an `UIView` with a `UIScrollView` (also three of them). `UIScrollView` will contain all the different parts of body (e.g. heads). `PageControl` will handle the swipe gesture recognition and animations and you will set which part of the `UIScrollView` should be shown in `UIPageControl`s event `ValueChanged`. The code will look something like this:

In `ViewDidLoad`:
First you add the five head parts to `UIScrollView`. I assume that you have these five head parts in an array of `UIView`s called `headPageViews`.

```
RectangleF frame;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    UIView pageView = headPageViews[i];
    frame = headPageViews[i].Frame;
    // change Frame.X so that the views are next to each other in scrollView
    frame.X = i * this.scrollViewHead.Frame.Width;
    pageView.Frame = frame;
    this.scrollViewHead.AddSubViews(pageView);
}
```

In `ViewDidLoad`: Next you set up the `UIPageControl` which you added through interface builder:

```
this.pageControlHead = new UIPageControl(frame);
this.pageControlHead.HidesForSinglePage = true;
this.pageControlHead.ValueChanged += HandlePageControlHeadValueChanged;
this.pageControlHead.Pages = 5; this.viewHead.AddSubview(this.pageControlHead);
```

Somewhere in code: At last you handle the `ValueChanged` event:

```
private void HandlePageControlHeadValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.scrollViewHead.SetContentOffset(new PointF(this.pageControlHead.CurrentPage * this.scrollViewHead.Frame.Width, 0), true);
}
```

Repeat these steps for other body parts and you should have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 3 **UIScrollViews** in a **UIViewController** positioned as the image you have added, and set that **UIScrollView** to enable paging.
set the cropped sections of image in those **UIScrollViews**, then you would be able to achieve it easily.

Hope this helps.