# scroll images with page control in Xamarin

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I try to write application in Xamarin which uses page controll for switching images, I used this article as tutorial http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.ru/2013/01/page-control-for-switching-between-views.html but I can't scroll my images, and in debug it is not stoping at breakpoint in method scrolled.
My code:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();;
        scrollView.PagingEnabled = true;
        scrollView.ContentSize = new SizeF(scrollView.Frame.Width * 2,scrollView.Frame.Height);
        scrollView.ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
        scrollView.ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
        scrollView.ScrollsToTop = false;

        scrollView.Scrolled += delegate
        {
            var pageWidth = scrollView.Frame.Size.Width;
            var page = (int)Math.Floor((scrollView.ContentOffset.X - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
            pageControl.CurrentPage = page;
        };

        var pic = new UIImage ("first.png");
        var img = new UIImageView (pic);

        var pic2 = new UIImage ("second.png");
        var img2 = new UIImageView (pic2);

        var imageArray = new UIImageView[]{img,img2};

        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {


            RectangleF frame = new RectangleF ();
            frame.X = scrollView.Frame.Size.Width * i;
            frame.Y = 0;
            frame.Size = scrollView.Frame.Size;

            imageArray [i].Frame = frame;


            scrollView.AddSubview (imageArray[i]);
        }

        scrollView.ContentSize = new SizeF(scrollView.Frame.Size.Width*2,scrollView.Frame.Size.Height);

    }
```

also I tryed to create my own delegate class and set scrollView.Delegate = new ScrollViewDelegate(this).

can it be problem if I use storyboard? In connection inspector 
for scroll view:
Outlets:
delegate - Page control
Referencing Outlets:
scrollView FirstViewController
for page control:
Referencing Outlets:
delegate = Scroll View

Comment: Does it located inside another scrollview?

Comment: @choper no it is located at view, like view->scrollview->pagecontroll

Comment: Please check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682748/sliding-images-with-xamarin/19705197#19705197

Answer (score 1):

I have done this once. What you need to do is:
You need 2 view controllers,

> **UIPageviewController***(parent controller)*
>   **ImageViewController** *(controller that has UIImageView)*

1. Create a **UIPageviewController**(parent controller), override its **GetNextViewController** and **GetPreviousViewController** methods.
2. Maintain a Page number counter in this parent controller page.
3. I am assuming you would have a **List< UIImage >**
4. Here in **GetNextViewController** method you will **increment** the counter and display the List< UIImage >(Page No Counter) and return ImageViewController
5. Here in **GetPreviousViewController** method you will **decrement** the counter and display the List< UIImage >(Page No Counter) and return ImageViewController

Hope this helps